# Ajax Post request by Request onSymfony4

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, symfony4

I send POST ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: {{getforwardhist}},
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: [{"id" : 3}],
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("reload ajax");
    }
});
```

in php

```
/**
 * @Route("/member/getforwardhist", name="getforwardhist",methods={"POST"})
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function getForwardHist(Request $request){  

    $id = $request->request->get('id'); //Not get ID
```

When I use GET request `$request->query->get('id')` works but for POST, `$request->query->get('id');`

I think this is the most simple implementation though, I can't find the cause of this error.

Is there anything I need to check??

Comment: `data: [{"id" : 3}]`...here you are sending an array containing an object, but it seems like the server-side code is expecting a simple object. Try `data: {"id" : 3}` instead.

Comment: Thank you I completely misunderstood..... It works well  now.